# If I reject the null on a two sample t-test, can I conclude which direction the difference goes?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, inference, central-limit-theorem

Since it's a two-sided test, it seems plausible that **I can only reject that the difference is 0**. However, if the entire interval is negative or positive can I say that one is larger or smaller than the other (with confidence 1-alpha) or do I need a different test? If I need a different test to establish that one is greater than the other, which one should I use?

Comment: It is not clear why a hypothesis test is relevant here, as opposed to a confidence interval.

Comment: We reject iff the CI does not include 0 - is this true?

Comment: Why not simply give the CI itself? What does the test show you that the CI doesn't?

Comment: @Glen_b said it well.  Dichotomies are bad, continuous estimation is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell which mean is bigger by looking at the means.

But you can only reject the null hypothesis that you tested, which is that the two means are equal.

Comment: I want to make statements about the difference of population means mu1-mu2. If I reject the null and the CI is > 0, can I determine formally that mu1 is larger than mu2 with confidence 1-alpha? If not, what other test will establish the direction? Thanks

Comment: Sure. An evil scientist trapped a statistician in a locked chamber containing only a thermometer. "Tell me whether the temperature is changing!" commanded the villain. After collecting data, the statistician conducted a two-sided t-test and concluded the temperature indeed had changed. As he announced this, he also added--shivering uncontrollably because it had become so wickedly cold--that it was nevertheless impossible to tell whether he was being roasted alive or frozen to death. Wuschelbeutel, if you think like this statistician, then you do need another test. Otherwise you're just fine.

Comment: @whuber Hehe. Yeah, it is possible to get too formal.

Answer (score 1):

The t-test compares means. So just compute the means of your two samples and wherever it is larger, that's the sample with the significantly larger mean.

Most statistical packages should actually give you not only a p-value, but also the difference of means (as well as the pooled standard deviation/error etc.).

The t-test is appropriate if you want to know whether the mean of the population where one sample was drawn is greater than in the other. The test is applicable to virtually all data as long as you have sufficiently large sample sizes.